# How can I fix blazor dropdown onchange and bind problem?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, blazor

I am trying to learn blazor.I am completely new learner on blazor. Suppose I had saved a department under a company. But now I want to change the company. I have a department list page where have a edit button. When I click edit button I want to load department name and company drop down with selected company. To achieve this I am using the following code and it work fine.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="input-group">
    <label class="col-md-3">Department Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" @bind="department.Name" />
    </div>
</div><br />
<div class="input-group">
    <label class="col-md-3">Company</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <select class="form-control" @bind="@comId">
            @if (company != null && company.Any())
            {
                <option>Select Company</option>

                foreach (var c in company)
                {

                    <option value="@c.Id">@c.Name</option>
                }

            }
            else
            {
                <option>Select Company</option>
            }

        </select>
    </div>
</div><br />
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="button" value="Update" @onclick="UpdateDepartment" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
    </div>
</div>
```

But When I am trying to add @onchange event at  `<select class="form-control" @bind="@comId" @onchange="SelectCompany">` it generate error. So how can I get the new value of company from dropdown. The server side code for blazor bellow

```
@code {

[Parameter]
public string id { get; set; }

string baseUrl;
Company[] company;
Department department = new Department();
int SelectedCompanyVal = 0;
int comId = 0;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    baseUrl = AppSettingsService.GetBaseUrl();
    department = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Department>(baseUrl + "api/Departments/GetDepartment/" + id);
    var url = baseUrl + "api/Companies/GetCompanies";
    company = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Company[]>(url);
    comId = department.CompanyId;
}
protected async Task UpdateDepartment()
{
    department.CompanyId =SelectedCompanyVal;
    await Http.PutJsonAsync(baseUrl + "api/Departments/PutDepartment/" + id, department);
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("listDepartment");
}
void  SelectCompany(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
    SelectedCompanyVal = Convert.ToInt32(e.Value.ToString());
}
}
```

Comment: I think using `@bind` is creating an `@onchange` below the surface. So it should already work without an additional onchange.

Comment: Thanks. I have remove @onchange and made some change my code it works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I have change some back end logic and and remove @onchange method now it is working for me. My new back end code is

```
@code {

[Parameter]
public string id { get; set; }

string baseUrl;
Company[] company;
Department department = new Department();   
int comId = 0;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    baseUrl = AppSettingsService.GetBaseUrl();
    department = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Department>(baseUrl + "api/Departments/GetDepartment/" + id);
    var url = baseUrl + "api/Companies/GetCompanies";
    company = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Company[]>(url);
    comId = department.CompanyId;
}


protected async Task UpdateDepartment()
{
    department.CompanyId = comId;
    await Http.PutJsonAsync(baseUrl + "api/Departments/PutDepartment/" + id, department);
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("listDepartment");
}
}
```

And the frontend is same as I posted